# Add a new CSS class in Chrome developer tool

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible to add a whole new CSS class like this in Chrome dev tools?

```
.myclass {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: click on `.cls` and add your class name

Comment: @kumbhanibhavesh not only is it an attempt to answer instead of a comment, but in addition this is a wrong answer to that question. This just adds a a class to the inspected element and doesn't let you create a brand new class in CSS..

Answer (score 37, accepted):

On the `Elements` tab there's a `styles` tab which contains a small **+** button on the right side.

[image: New Style Rule]

When you click here, you can add a whole new CSS class.

[image]

Once you've defined the new class, see [Add a class to an element](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css/reference#add-class) to learn how to apply it to an element. You could also just double-click the element in the **DOM Tree** on the **Elements** panel to add or edit the element's `class` attribute.

Comment: how to add class that does not fades out on page refresh

Comment: You could use a Chrome extensions like **User JavaScript and CSS**: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-javascript-and-css/nbhcbdghjpllgmfilhnhkllmkecfmpld?hl=en